# Problema con GITHUB

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, git, github

tengo un problema con GITHUB al subir mi proyecto, estoy utilizando dos carpeta donde se separan el Frontend que es con React y el backend con Nodejs, el problema lo tengo con el frontend, yo al subir sigo todos los pasos que me dice github para subir a mi repositorio, pero cuando llego hacer el **git add .** me aparece en la consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero despues hago otro ***git add .*** y ya no me aparece y lo subo normalmente, pero cuando me fijo las carpeta en mi repositorio en GITHUB me aparece asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

osea la carpeta frontend esta con una linea y si quiero ingresar no me deja, y ahora cuando quiero subir los cambios no puedo por que me aparece estos errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien sabe por que me aparece estos problemas y como poder solucionarlo? yo solo cree un repositorio

Comment: Tenes que borrar el .git de la carpeta frontend, y para ver la carpeta .git tenes que marcar la opcion de ver los archivos ocultos si usas windows

Comment: hay me funciona, pero tuve que volver a subir otra vez, osea eliminando mi git y el git del frontend, muchas gracias